# Force Cycles GPU rendering for a Render Farm

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

So basically I'm on vacation for 2 weeks with a laptop without a CUDA device. I do have access to a render farm with GPU rendering support.

Now the problem is that I can't setup blender to render in GPU and send the file to the farm because the laptop doesn't support it.

The farm has script support if that info helps.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28480/how-do-i-force-the-netrender-to-render-everything-on-gpu/28513#28513 ? An explanation: https://www.dalaifelinto.com/?p=746

Answer (score -1):

Send it to the farm that will let you change the settings or they will change it for you. Try GarageFarm.NET as they have super friendly support working 24/7

Comment: Nope. No option to change the device after the upload. I'm at Lion Render. And no, because I already payed 50 bucks for the very needed unlimited plan. But yes, next time I'll stick to what I know, being Render Street