# How to ensure Blender uses the GPU when running from the command line on a headless Linux computer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, command-line

I have Blender installed on a Linux machine with 6 Nvidia GPUs (GTX 1060)

I have an `ssh` connection into it but it doesn’t look like Blender is using the GPUs. The command I am using is as follows:

```
Sudo blender -b RenderTest.blend -a -o <location>
```

It's taking around 2 minutes to render a frame, on my Windows PC it took 1 minute with a single 1080TI, using the `top` command it shows my CPU at 200% indicating it's currently using 2 CPU threads.

How can I fix this so it uses all 6 GPUs?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE. Have you tried launching Blender together with a script for setting up the GPU calculation, as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28513)?

Comment: @NicolaSap I tried that script, however nvidia-smi shows that the gpus are not running any processes